# How to use CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES macro in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I need link my program against Kerberos authentication library (`gssapi_krb5`) with the corresponding headers `gssapi/gssapi.h` and `gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h` included in the source file.

Currently, the compilation will continue if headers are absent and stop with a compile time error saying header files not found.
What I want to implement in the cmake file is to check the existence of the header file and stop compiling if not found.

I add the following code into my `CMakeList.txt` file.

```
INCLUDE(CheckIncludeFiles)

CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES(gssapi/gssapi.h;gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h HAVE_KRB_HEADERS)
IF (NOT HAVE_KRB_HEADERS)
    RETURN()
ENDIF (NOT HAVE_KRB_HEADERS)
```

But it still does not act as I expected.
I would like the following lines:

```
-- Looking for gssapi/gssapi.h - found
-- Looking for gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h - not found
```

but fail.
Also, the variable `HAVE_KRB_HEADERS` is empty when output with `message` macro.
Compile continues until the error described above occurs.

I read somewhere on the Web, this may be because CMake cache.
I'm very new to CMake and not quite clear with that concept.
My CMake version is 2.6.
How could I make this code work? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't say I'm a huge fan of `CheckIncludeFiles` because of its difficulty to get right.  In principal it's good - it actually creates tiny c files which `#include` the requested headers and tries to compile them, but it seems to be too easy to get wrong.

I generally prefer just using [`find_path`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afind_path) and/or [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afind_file) for this job.  This doesn't check the contents of any files found, but usually if you find the required header, its contents are good!

I would use `find_path` if I needed to know the *folder* where the header lived.  This would usually be because I need to check for other files in the same folder (as in your case), or more commonly because I need to add the folder to an [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories) call.

`find_file` yields the full path to the file (if found).  For headers, normally I don't need the path elsewhere in the CMakeLists - it's just used immediately after the `find_file` to check the file was actually found.

So, here's how I'd go about checking for "gssapi/gssapi.h" and "gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h"

```
find_path(GssApiIncludes gssapi.h PATHS <list of folders you'd expect to find it in>)
if(NOT GssApiIncludes)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't find folder containing gssapi.h")
endif()

find_file(GssKrb gssapi_krb5.h PATHS ${GssApiIncludes} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
if(NOT GssKrb)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't find gssapi_krb5.h in ${GssApiIncludes}")
endif()
```

If you do this, then if required you could add

```
include_directories(${GssApiIncludes})
```

so that in your source code you can do

```
#include "gssapi.h"
#include "gssapi_krb5.h"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. And I have almost banged my head against the `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` wall for a whole afternoon. Still have some points unclear. I apologise if my question is too silly. The first is about `FIND_PATH`: if the header files are in regular include folders (`/usr/include/` in my case), is it unnecessary to invoke it? Second, if the `PATHS` in `FIND_FILE` not a must? I omit this parameter, it still works. The last is a more general one: could you please share some experience learning CMake. Exactly speaking, CMake is an alien language to me, although I've read some tutor.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea - Q1: Probably worth still checking they exist, even if they're in `/usr/include`. Q2: `PATHS` is always optional.  When reading the CMake docs, anything inside `[`...`]` brackets is optional. Q3: For me, learning was mostly trial-and-error. Subscribing to the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/mailman/listinfo/cmake) helped get a feel for the "right way" to do things and taught me more than I expected it would.  There are a lot of real experts on the mailing list.  The [CMake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake) is also a decent resource.

Comment: The last part of your answer is not good practice. Normally one should only include directories that end in 'include/' and if that contains a subdirectory then use that in your source code. For example, if /usr/local/weird/include/foo/conf.h exists you add `-I /usr/local/weird/include` and use `#include "foo/conf.h"` in your source code. The reason being that without the 'foo' part you get too easily namespace collision of the header file names. Now it is unlikely that another library has a `gssapi.h`, but this is still the normal/best way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has to work with `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES`, the documentation lists a variable called [`CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFiles.html#:%7E:text=CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES) where you can set additional include paths apart from the default headers.

In a CMake file:

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "gssapi")
```

From the command line:

```
cmake . --DCMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES="gssapi"
```

If all else fails, you can set the `-I<dir>` flag manually. However, this is not recommended as it not portable across compilers.

```
# note the extra space before `-I`
STRING(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS " -Igssapi")
STRING(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Igssapi") # for C++
```

Also note that C++ headers have a different macro called [`CheckIncludeFileCXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFileCXX.html#module:CheckIncludeFileCXX).